Unable to assign value of object key within array of objects
I'm getting below error:

Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.

for assignment within mutateData function. Do not really understand why, because data is initialised as empty array with proper type.
type FileObject = {
    name: string
    path: string
    returnStatus: number
    dataPrepared: boolean
}

type Keys = keyof FileObject

type KeyValue = {
    [key in Keys]: {key: key, value: FileObject[key]}
}[Keys]

type Mutation = {
    index: number
} & KeyValue

const data: FileObject[] = []

function mutateData(input: Mutation) {
    data[input.index][input.key] = input.value
}

Playground
Above solution should work in my opinion as Mutation type consist of index and proper union types of key/value pairs.
Edit:
Below code and playground consists of my real use case, I would like to have single type for switch statement and most importantly to avoid generic.
type FileObject = {
    name: string
    path: string
    returnStatus: number
    dataPrepared: boolean
}

type Keys = keyof FileObject

type KeyValue = {
    [key in Keys]: {key: key, value: FileObject[key]}
}[Keys]

type Mutation = {
    switchType: 'singleValue'
    index: number
} & KeyValue

type ReturnObject = {
    switchType: 'returnObject'
    index: number
}

type DataHandler = Mutation | ReturnObject

const data: FileObject[] = []

function dataHandler(input: DataHandler) {
    switch (input.switchType) {
        case 'singleValue':
            data[input.index][input.key] = input.value
            break
        case 'returnObject':
            console.log(data[input.index])
            break
        default:
            return
    }
}

Playground 2

This is a correlated union, which isn't directly supported; see ms/TS#30581. The recommended refactoring is to use generics instead; see ms/TS#47109. For your example it looks like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz thanks, I have edited my question to address my real use case

seems you cannot avoid using generics here

• Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

(see prev comment) • You've mostly just expanded the scope of the question in response to a suggested solution, which isn't great... but still, you need generics, because at base it's still a correlated union issue. Why do you want to avoid generics? You say "most importantly" but not why it matters. At this point the answer to the question is "you can't do it" unless you lift the restriction against generics. Well, or you can just use a type assertion like this to forget type safety. How shall we proceed here?

Thank you for the reply, in the first place I didn't know that there might be an issue with the correlated union type but indeed I should have refered to the suggested soultion... my bad. My, let say, reasoning for not using generic was the fact that since DataHandler contains all the necessary types I wouldn't want to create a generic consisting type already included in DataHandler - in my real code, switch statement sits in a different component than types declaration. But now knowing I need to use generic, that is understandable and I'll accept @hoangdv reply. Thanks once again.

Let's make Mutation type and mutateData function become generics.
FileObject key name will be the generic parameter:
type FileObject = {
    name: string
    path: string
    returnStatus: number
    dataPrepared: boolean
}

type ReturnObject = {
    switchType: 'returnObject'
    index: number
}

type Mutation<T extends keyof FileObject> = { switchType: 'singleValue'; index: number; key: T; value: FileObject[T] }

type DataHandler<T extends keyof FileObject> = Mutation<T> | ReturnObject

const data: FileObject[] = []

function dataHandler<T extends keyof FileObject>(input: DataHandler<T>) {
    switch (input.switchType) {
        case 'singleValue':
            data[input.index][input.key] = input.value
            break
        case 'returnObject':
            console.log(data[input.index])
            break
        default:
            return
    }
}


thanks, I have edited my question to address my real use case

@MajkelTMB Updated, but still using generic.
